Some updates do not work on other browsers
I made some changes in my Wordpress site (navigation or block styles), it works well when I open on the browser that I used to make the changes (in which I sign in with my admin account) i.e Google Chrome. But when I open in others as Edge, Brave, the changes does not seem to take effect. I have cleared all cookies and caches, try to open in incognito mode, it's still the same.
Where it could go wrong and how can I fix it? Thank you.

Are changes appearing if you login (WP Admin) to the browser (Edge, Brave).

I have just tried and it does appear if I login to WP Admin when using other browsers. Why it looks different when I use another account?

This could be due to Server Side Cache or Network Cache, Confirm to try this on different device (and different internet if possible) without login.

I open the site in another device (mobile) but I have used this one to open the site before, and changes do not appear. Do you know how to clear those kinds of caches? Because I would eventually need to review changes in this device anyway, cause you cant find new device every time making changes.

Server site cache can disabled from server, or if you do not have access you can contact Hosting provider, on the other hand network cache can be resolved by contacting ISP, I think it's not related to Network Cache.

Thanks alot, I'll try.

You're welcome :).
